# Javascript & php reloading div content not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I'm having problems reloading content in a div and for the life of my I don't understand why. The code below works on one page but for whatever reason doesn't on another despite being exactly the same bar the file that is loaded.

Every time after the post I need to manually refresh the page to see the latest data.

page1.php

```
<form method="post">
<button id="SendLogsBtn" name="SendLogsBtn" class="CheckConnectionBtn" button onclick="ShowWaiting()">Start</button>
</form>

  <div id="mydiv" style="display:none;">
    <p> <?php include('file1.log'); ?> </p>
  </div>

  <?php include 'page1include.php'; ?>
```

page1inclulde.php

```
if (isset($_POST['SendLogsBtn'])) {
    $output = shell_exec("/myscript.sh");
    $_SESSION["mysession"] = "SET";
}

if (isset($_SESSION['mysession'])) {
    echo '<script>$( "#mydiv" ).load( "file1.log" );</script>';
    echo '<script>document.getElementById("mydiv").style.display = "block";</script>';
}
```

The div unhides just fine but for whatever reason the file1.log isn't reloaded so it displays old data from before the script was executed (the script outputs to file1.log).

All I want is for file1.log to be reloaded after my script has finished.

What am I doing wrong and what is the best way to achieve what I want in a reliable way?

Comment: would you try to change the form to ```<form method="post">
<input type='hidden' name="SendLogsBtn"/> <button id="SendLogsBtn" name="SendLogsBtn" class="CheckConnectionBtn" onclick="ShowWaiting()">Start</button>
</form>```

Comment: Unfortunately all that does is hide the button after clicking it. The problem isn't with the button but with reloading file1.log.

Comment: ```<script>$( "#mydiv" ).load( "file1.log" );</script>```may be the problem. i suggest you to add ```<script>setTimeout(function(){location.reload();},500)</script>```

Comment: Can I ask why you load file1.log with Javascript and why you simply don't just execute /myscript.sh _before_ you include file1.log with php?

Comment: The script is only executed after the user clicks a button. I'm pretty new to php and javascript so not sure how to load it after the button has been clicked.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use a sleep with a couple of seconds after shell_exec. Maybe it's because the PHP isn't waiting for the shell_exec response to continue the execution;
Or you are giving a response on your myscript.sh before the execution ends and the PHP thinks that the script ended and continues the execution of your PHP script.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. It was (no surprise) my own incompetence. I think I've just been staring at my own code too long because after looking at it again after giving it a rest for a day I noticed I had two lines of code both trying to refresh the same div/file.

I think that is what caused the problem because after removing one of the lines it's now working reliably. Though I don't quite understand why it didn't work before. I would expect the div to simply be reloaded twice rather than not at all.